# Why do [[ -z ]] and [[ -v ]] have different syntax?

Tags: bash, variable, test

If I want to perform some commands given variables aren't set I'm using:

```
if [[ -z "$a" || -z "$v" ]]
then
  echo "a or b are not set"
fi
```

Yet the same syntax doesn't work with `-v`, I have to use:

```
if [[ -v a && -v b ]]
then
  echo "a & b are set"
fi
```

What is the history behind this? I don't understand why the syntax wouldn't be the same. I've read that `-v` is a somewhat recent addition to bash *(4.2)*?

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking why you need to use the dollar sign?

Comment: a variable can be set to `""`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Test operators `-v` and `-z` are just not the same.

Operator `-z` tells if a string is empty. So it is true that `[[ -z "$a" ]]` will give a good approximation of "variable `a` is unset",
but not a perfect one:

- the expression will yield true if `a` is set to the empty string
  rather than unset;
- the enclosing script will fail if `a` is unset and the option
  `nounset` is enabled.

On the other hand, `-v a` will be exactly "variable `a` is set", even
in edge cases. It should be clear that passing `$a` rather than `a` to
`-v` would not be right, as it would expand that possibly-unset
variable before the test operator sees it; so it has to be part of
that operator's task to inspect that variable, pointed to by its name,
and tell whether it is set.

Comment: When you say edge case do you mean they handle empty differently? For example `a=""`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Note that there are edge cases for `[[ -v ]]` as well. Like for a variable _array_ type, `[[ -v var ]]` returns true only if `${var[0]}` (in effect same as `$var`) is set. For associative array, `${var[0]}` as well (not `${var[00]}` for instance). `[[ -v var[@] ]]` would return true if the array has any value set (would return false for a variable set as `var=()`). That's down to the crazy way variable typing is done in ksh/bash. See `zsh` for a less confusing variable typing.

Comment: Ah, good point. You noticed how I carefully didn't get into the array issue :).

Comment: More succinctly: `-z` tests a value, while `-a` tests a *name*.

Comment: @chepner, do you mean -v tests a name?

Comment: @tedyyu Oof, yes. `-z` tests a value, `-v` tests a name.

Answer (score 7):

There's a difference in the meaning of `-z` and `-v`:

```
echo Empty:
x=""  # Same with x=
[[ -z $x ]] && echo z
[[ -v  x ]] && echo v
unset x

echo Unset
[[ -z $x ]] && echo z
[[ -v  x ]] && echo v
```

By using `-z`, you can't distinguish a variable that was assigned an empty value from a variable that hasn't been assigned any value.

Also, `[[ -z $x ]]` is still sensible to `set -u`, while `[[ -v x ]]` isn't.